# recent topics in linguistics

Tags: sociolinguistics, pragmatics

What are the **recent controversial issues** in:

- **pragmatics**
- **socio-linguistics**

that are receiving the experts' attention?

Comment: Luna, welcome to Linguistics but this question is asking for suggestions and we don't deal with such topics. :) Please take a moment to read our [Help Center](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help), especially the part about what you can and cannot ask.

Comment: If you're talking about a dissertation, you need to consult with your advisor. You don't mention where you're studying nor who you're studying with. That makes a lot more difference in picking a dissertation topic than suggestions from the public.

Comment: sorry i didn't know that @Alenanno .

Comment: @luna No problem, and sorry for the inconvenience, but those are the rules. However, enjoy the site and if you have more questions, we are here!

Comment: well i am editing this question as sugggested by you & tim osborne

Comment: @luna Ok, in your new edits, are you referring to some specific issues? If so, which ones? Add that to your question.

Comment: @alenanno no specific issues, i am actually asking the researchers and experts of the field about the latest issues,topics, theories in linguistics.

Comment: @luna There are two problems: **1.** your new question is fundamentally different from the first version. **2.** your new version is very broad, you could find books on the same topic. You should try to ask more specific things. Have you visited our Help Center?

Comment: yes i did , the question itself is broad only specifies the field, i am asking about any topic in sociolinguistics and pragmatics that you have read about, or done research on .

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE! Thank you for editing but the new version is fundamentally different and broad. You can actually also google this and find almost 10,000 results about your question. Try to google first then if that doesn't help try adding details about what you found and why it doesn't work for you by [editing](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/posts/6943/edit). Also, suggestions are opinion-based. Please read the [Help Center](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help) for why your question was closed. Sorry for the inconvenience but please edit this to make it more specific.

Comment: @zixuan Please stop bumping ancient posts unless the edits make a real substantial difference. There is no value in changing the formatting from posts of 5 years ago **and** you actually made it worse by using a wrong apostrophe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are not yet near being in a position to select a dissertation topic in linguistics. Locating a good dissertation topic depends on a number of factors. In particular, it should be something that your/a thesis advisor and dissertation committee have at least some understanding of. A good dissertation topic will fascinate you. To know what fascinates you in linguistics, you will have gained exposure to a number of subfields. You then probe for a good topic in the particular subfield that you find most interesting.

If your question had been phrased as follows, you would probably be closer to locating a potential dissertation topic: "I am looking for a good dissertation topic in pragmatics. What are a couple of key issues in pragmatics that are controversial and receiving attention by experts in the field?".

Since one is likely to spend a couple of years working on a dissertation, the subject matter has to be something that one finds really interesting. Without the inspiration, one can flounder for years trying to complete the project.

While my knowledge of socio-linguistics and pragmatics is sparse, I might be able to respond insightfully to a more narrow question concerning syntactic theory. Others in this forum might also be able to respond insightfully if the question is expressed more narrowly, addressing the particular subfield that interests you and them.

Comment: well it is for applying in a university abroad that's why i don't have a supervisor

Comment: Oh! That strikes me as unusual. A graduate program that is expecting potential grad students to know what they want to write their dissertation about before they have done any graduate coarse work, that's strange, and probably unreaslistic. I suggest looking up the faculty members in the department you are applying to. Find out what their specialties are, and then propose something rather vague that is in the specialty area of one of those faculty members. Note that I did not settle on my dissertation topic until after three years of graduate coarse work.

Comment: well it is in France they ask for a research proposal to apply for a master since their students already prepared a short dissertation in their third year of licence , but unfortunately at my university we didn't write any academic dissertation yet.

Comment: In North America and most of Europe, the term "dissertation" refers to a thesis that one writes to achieve the title of "doctor of philosophy". It gets you your Ph.D. A master's thesis is by no means a dissertation. Big difference. A master's thesis is a much less serious and lengthy matter.

Comment: yes there's a difference in the use of the word "dissertation",  in France & north Africa it is an academic composition of 50-150 pages at the master level , and the "memoire" at the end of the licence .